# Angular 6: Change property of an object and save it to the database (In-memory Web API)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

I have a class:

```
export class Thing {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    link: string;
    liked: boolean;
}
```

A database (In-memory Web API):

```
    createDb() {
        const things = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Ian",
            link:"http://1",
            liked:false
        },
            ...
    ];
        return {things};
    }
```

template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let thing of things">
      <p>id:{{thing.id}}</p>
      <p>name: {{thing.name}}</p>
      <p>link: {{thing.link}}</p>
      <label>
         <p>{{thing.liked}}</p>
         <input ([ngModel])="thing.liked" type="checkbox" data="toggle" (change)=onLike(thing)>
  </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

things.component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Thing } from '../thing';
import { ThingService } from '../thing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  templateUrl: './thing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thing.component.css']
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {

  things: Thing[];
  @Input() thing: Thing;

  constructor(private thingService: ThingService) { }

  getThings(): void {
    this.thingService.getThings()
        .subscribe(things => this.things = things);
  }

  onLike(x): void{
    x.liked = !x.liked;
    this.thingService.saveThing(x).subscribe(things => this.things = things);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getThings();
  }

}
```

thingService method:

```
saveThing(thing: Thing): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put(this.thingsUrl, thing, httpOptions)
  }
```

When I click on a checkbox I expect "liked" property to change it's value (it does) and object "thing" to be saved to the database with this new value of "liked" (instead of that - after "liked" value is changed the whole list is gone). Where's the problem?

UPD:

I've added the getThings() method to be called on a change of a checkbox

```
  onLike(x): void{
    x.liked = !x.liked;
    this.thingService.saveThing(x).subscribe(things => this.things = things);
    this.getThings();
  }
```

But I want this value to stay in a new condition when the page is refreshed. It doesn't

Comment: The list is gone from the database? Or the front end?

Comment: If the data is still in the database but not showing on the front end, make sure the API is returning the new collection of things, because you're doing `.subscribe(things => this.things = things);`

Comment: I did some update to the question.

Comment: One problem I see with this update - you call `this.getThings()` without waiting for `this.thingService.saveThing(x)` to complete. But I'm not sure that's your whole issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the in-memory-web-api, it doesn't persists the data, the createDb will run again and ngOnInit will run again. If using a real web api, it will fetch the data that is stored in the database since ngOnInit will run on page refresh. If you want to persist data when refreshing then you need to store it in localstorage or a real database

Comment: I'm learning Angular with this tutorial now - https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6. In the tutorial they're using in-memory-web-api and it keeps new values after refreshing.

Comment: Not on refreshing the page, there's no where in that tutorial that it is persisting data to a database, file or localstorage. The entire angular app is going to be reinitialize on page refresh.

Comment: If you add console.log("app loaded") under createDb() method you'll see it will run every time you refresh the page. It's a single page app so anytime the page is refereshed the OnInit methods are going to run and so will createDb